# Rails 3.2 Oauth2 gem and examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, rubygems

I need to implement an API for an app using OAUTH.

I already did one using OAUTH v1, I'd like to try to use OAUTH v2, but I'm unsure which gem(s) I should use, I can't find a definitive one to go with.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [OAuth Plugin](https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin) in the past and it worked fine for me.